# In Excel what value returned by a function will be ignored by a sort

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in a worksheet where in one column there is a function that generates data based on other inputs in the same row. If the function does not have enough data to make a valid return it should not return anything (to prevent it being caught up in a sort).

Setup Example: Column A is filled with random values (0-1) [copy paste values of function `=rand()`]. Column 2 has the function `=IF(A1<0.5,"text"&A1,"")`. Sort column `B` from A->Z. The blank `""` cells show up first. How can I make it so that a user can sort in either direction and the blank cells get pushed to the bottom of the list.

Note the example function is only an example, my equation is different but still returns text or blank/empty

I've tried `=if(A1="something","",A1)` and `=if(A1="something",,A1)`but both still get sorted.

Restriction:

1) I know I can do this in VBA with an `on change` populate the cell or clear it, but this project is being sent to and received from 3rd party sources and the users are not technical enough to validate received files with signatures or hashes.

2) The table is dynamic with older values being removed and new ones being added. The function in the column must remain a function. Copy and paste values is also off the table as a solution.

Comment: you will need to copy paste the values then sort.  Formulas are live and will update as the date to which they refer changes the sort order.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner for your suggestion. I've updated the post to add a new restriction. Your solution would of worked if it wasn't for the fact that the function can't be removed.

Comment: Then there is no solution.  Formula are live and will change when sorted.  Either vba or copy/paste would need to be utilized.

Comment: @ScottCraner That was my conclusion as well. I was/am still hoping someone can prove me wrong.